# Blazor Server Best Practices About Coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Monitoring Dashboard Application using Blazor Server.

It contains 5 pages and each page have 5 to 10 components to show.

I want users to switch between pages quickly like desktop app.

I want to do everything right while I'm still at the beginning.

What I'm currently doing is;

1. I code everything in same razor.cs file for each page.

- Q: Each page almost contains 1000 lines of code. Should I split it? If yes, how so?

2. by loading and updating all 5 pages in the background, I want users switch between pages quickly like desktop application.

- Q: I feel like this is not the best way to do it, Are there any?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: Each page almost contains 1000 lines of code. Should I split it? If yes, how so?

Instead of handling everything in the .razor component, make a service class (Check out Dependency injection) and create methods that takes in the necessary inputs and then spew out the result. Blazor is very service-oriented. Check out Clean Architecture, and my recommendation; DDD (Domain-driven design).

> by loading and updating all 5 pages in the background, I want users switch between pages quickly like desktop application.

> Q: I feel like this is not the best way to do it, Are there any?

I don't understand what you mean by "loading and updating all 5 pages in the background". I can only guess you want fast page load when navigating between the 5 pages? If so, Blazor Server is already very quick in loading since it's done through the SignalR connection.

Make sure to read about the Blazor Lifecycle, and place logic/service-calls in the right places, to prevent slow page loads.

PS. In .NET 8, we'll have Fullstack Blazor with SSR, interactive server and interactive WASM all in one project. This allows you to diplay the website immediately through the interactive server-mechanism, and download the WASM (WebAssembly) in the background, so the next time you load the page, it will feel like a desktop app.

This gives you more opportunities and enhance your application if you know what you're doing. It's a good idea to start now. You can download the .NET 8 RC2 right now, and the general availability for the .NET 8 will be out in mid November.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be a very generic answer as there's no code to work with.

> Each page almost contains 1000 lines of code. Should I split it?

Yes: crazy size.  Read about Single Responsibility Principles.  Look at Clean Design for guidance on how to segregate your code.  Each bit of the screen should probably be a component encapsulating it's own logic.

> by loading and updating all 5 pages in the background, I want users switch between pages quickly like desktop application.

How?  You can't build components "in the background" and then use them as you wish.

You need to split out your data from your UI [first comment]. The data belongs in scoped services and can load in the background.  The UI will render fast as long it has the data on hand.

If all you are doing is viewing data, use records rather than classes to represent your data and turn off tracking on DbContexts if you are using them.